# JDBC ResultSet - Can't retrieve alias column

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

We have the follwing SQL-Query:

```
select Resa.ResID, Avgångdatum, Avgångtid, AvgångStad, AnkomstTid, AnkomstDatum, AnkomstStad, AntalPlatser, Kostnad,

    (select sum(Bokning.AntalBiljetter) from Bokning where Bokning.ResID = Resa.ResID) as EnkelBiljetter,

    (select sum(Bokning.AntalBiljetter) from Bokning where Resa.ResID in
        (select PaketResa.ResID from PaketResa where PaketResa.PaketID in
            (select PaketID from PaketResa where PaketResa.PaketID = Bokning.PaketID))) as PaketBiljetter

from Resa;
```

When we try to get the columns "Enkelbiljetter" and "PaketBiljetter" in java, with

```
Integer.parseInt(result.getObject("PaketBiljetter").toString()
```

It returns a nullpointerexception. We've tried adding the "?`useOldAliasMetadataBehavior=true`" to the connection-statement but the result is the same. Neither does putting the columnindex (10 and 11) in the getObject-method. We're using the 5.1.19 JDBC driver. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be either your `result` or `getObject(...)` returning a null pointer. Since there's a `getInt()` method you should try this first:

```
result.getInt("PaketBiljetter")
```

and see what happens.