# jdbc reading resultSet by colName issue for aliases

Tags: scala, jdbc, resultset

I have a generic repository with a method as:

```
object Queries {
  def getByFieldId(field: String, id: Int): String = {
    s"""
       |SELECT
       |  DF.id AS fileId,
       |  DF.name AS fileName,
       |  AG.id AS groupId,
       |  AG.name AS groupName
       |FROM $tableName DFG
       |INNER JOIN directory_files DF on DF.id = DFG.file_id
       |INNER JOIN ad_groups AG on AG.id = DFG.group_id
       |WHERE DFG.$field = $id
       |""".stripMargin
  }
}

def getByFieldId(field: String, id: Int): Try[List[Object]] = {
   try {
       val sqlQuery = Queries.getByFieldId("ad_group", 1)
       statement = conn.getPreparedStatement(sqlQuery)
       setParameters(statement, params)
    
       resultSet = statement.executeQuery()
       val metadata = resultSet.getMetaData
    
       val columnCount = metadata.getColumnCount
       val columns: ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer.empty
       for (i <- 1 to columnCount) {
         columns += metadata.getColumnName(i)
       }
    
       var item: List[Object] = List.empty
       while (resultSet.next()) {
         val row = columns.toList.map(x => resultSet.getObject(x))
         item = row
       }
    
       Success(item)
  } catch {
       case e: Any => Failure(errorHandler(e))
  } finally conn.closeConnection(resultSet, statement)
}
```

The problems is that my result set ignore the query aliases and return columns as `(id, name, id, name)` instead of `(fileId, fileName, groupId, groupName)`.

One solution found is to use column index instead of col names, but I'm not sure if this solution will cover entire app and will not break some other queries.

Maybe, another found solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910133/jdbc-resultset-cant-retrieve-alias-column) and if I'm right, I can still use colNames but need to get them together with colTypes, then inside `resultSet.next()` to call `getType` method for each as:

```
 // this part of code is not tested
 // this idea came to me writing this topic
 while (resultSet.next()) {
     val row = columns.toList.map(x => {
        x.colType match {
           case "string" => resultSet.getString(x.colName)
           case "integer" => resultSet.getInt(x.colName)
           case "decimal" => resultSet.getDecimal(x.colName)
           case _ => resultSet.getString(x.colName)
     })
     item = row
 }
```

Comment: Why don't you use ordinal (numbered) positions?

Comment: Because I'm not sure I used same order in all queries as in case classes fields :d

Comment: thx, I removed it. I added it because `jdbc` in `Scala` is imported from `Java`. There are some small differences by writting, but being same library, the problem persist in both languages I think :d

Comment: But a Java person (like myself) will have a very hard time deciphering your Scala code.

Comment: Which database? This is highly relevant and you are most probably not on Oracle (where it works as you expects)...

Comment: Hi @Marmite, MySQL is used

Comment: Yes, I assumed this based on the reference of `useOldAliasMetadataBehavior` - see my (sorry, not tested) answer. But I guess this would be the *only* chance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to use [`getColumnLabel`](http://javadox.com/org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client/1.1.7/org/mariadb/jdbc/MySQLResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnLabel(int)) instead of `getColumnName`

as [documented](http://javadox.com/org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client/1.1.7/org/mariadb/jdbc/MySQLResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnLabel(int))

> Gets the designated column's suggested title for use in printouts and displays. The suggested title is usually specified by the SQL AS clause. If a SQL AS is not specified, the value returned from getColumnLabel will be the same as the value returned by the getColumnName method.

Note that this is highly dependent on the used `RDBM`.

For `Oracle` both methods return the *alias* and there is no chance to get the *original column name*.

Comment: that's the solution, thanks. `. The suggested title is usually specified by the SQL AS clause. If a SQL AS is not specified, the value returned from getColumnLabel will be the same as the value returned by the getColumnName method`

Comment: Glead to hear that the `columnLabel`  in MySQL works @AlleXyS